# Unable to check for if a file exists and perform statement

Tags: javascript

I am very new to javascripting and html.
I have built a web page that is mostly used to load either txt or other html pages using  tag.

But I am trying to create a validation statement to check if the source file exists and load the iframe or if it doesn't to display a message.

I have tried the below code, but it just doesn't work.

Can anyone please help me?

```
<script>
        var url = checkfile('../folder/test.html');
        if (url.exists()){ 
<iframe id = "allviewer" src = "../folder/test.html"> < /iframe>
        } else { 
           < p > This file does not exist < /p>
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should already avoid adding the iframe in the script tag, if you want to check if the file exists you can use ajax but the ajax already allows you to see the content so the iframe is no longer really necessary

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function url_exists(url) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
            xhr.open("GET", url, false);
            xhr.send();
            if (xhr.status == 200) resolve(xhr);
            else reject(xhr.status);
        })
    }

    const file = '../folder/test.html';
    url_exists(file).then(t => {
        console.log(t.response); // show file content in the console
        ouputNode.innerHTML = `<iframe id="allviewer" src="${file}"></iframe>`;
    }).catch(e => {
        // on error
    });
</script>
<div id="ouputNode"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I have tested and the page does not show anything, even though the file exists.

Comment: I got the following on the console: [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
(anonymous) @ test.html:74
url_exists @ test.html:72
(anonymous) @ test.html:82
ServiceNode.html:75

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/pcarvalho/Documents/Work%20to%20do/SPT%20Config%20script/New%20Version/html/test.html' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
(anonymous) @ test.html:75
url_exists @ test.html:72
(anonymous) @ test.html:82

Comment: Install apache or nginx server on your computer don't use directly the file in your browser